# Did the Greeks have an offering of blood, wine and milk, similar to the Cretan one?

Tags: greek, rituals

So I found this big old book about ancient cultures and in it, the typical offering on Crete was blood, wine and milk. Mixed together in a big bowl. The book describes the mix as a symbol for the drink of gods.

It's interesting because I heard that Maasai tribe uses (or used) blood and milk from their livestock as their main food source.

But does this have to do anything with Greek culture? Did ancient Greeks had a similar ritual? Could this be the nectar and ambrosia?

Comment: When you are talking about Cretan offerings, can we assume you are referring to the [Minoan civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minoan_civilization)?

Comment: Similar ritual you could find in Dalmatia villages,but that includes only vine and goat milk,without blood.Something like that you also find in Iliad,XI Book,638-642,Nestores and Patrocles,vine and goat cheese.I think it is the same ritual in other version.Maybe earlier rituals includeed blood.

Comment: @yannis yes but the book said that the tradition continued even after the fall of Minoa.

Comment: The Greeks may have had offerings, like most religions, but it is said that the Greek gods did not like blood offerings, but it may be similar to the Cretans. Also, I do not believe that that is Nectar, simply because Nectar was the Greeks name for honey.